# Looping through Python string in search for keywords

Tags: python, string, repeat

I have created a little program that counts kewords in string. As you see, keywords are stored in txt file. Today I realized that if a word in string repeats then keyword counter wont increase its value. Particulary in this case "wrong" is keyword in txt file and in result count variable wil be 1 not 2.

How to make it work, so repeating words will be counted too?

```
source_text = 'this is wrong. What is wrong with you?' 
source_words = source_text.split()
count = 0    

word_list = []
with open('pozit.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        word_list.append(line.strip())

for word in word_list:
    if word in source_words:
        count += 1
```

Comment: `"wrong"` is in `source_words` only once. The other one is `"wrong."` (note the dot).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `.count()`:

```
with open('pozit.txt') as inputfile:
    count = 0
    for line in inputfile:
        count += line.count('wrong')
```

If you only want words in the linguistic sense, have a look at nltk's [tokenizer module](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html).

Comment: if suppose my test string is 'wrong xyz wrongxyz wronged' then this will give me count = 3 but it should be 1

Comment: @simonzack i would use NLTK if it was in English, this time its in different language - English only as example. Your solution works if i know the keyword that repeats. But if I don't? For example Each time text is different

Comment: @andris Have a look at `collections.counter`. NLTK works for languages other than English as well.